# What's the best practice setting a default value to a const reference DataFrame argument in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

In a Rcpp function `foo`, the argument `data` may be a big dataframe so that I'd like use it as a const reference. Now I want to set the default value of it as an empty dataframe, so that users can simply call `foo()` but not `foo(data.frame())` in R.

I've tried this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame foo(const DataFrame &data = DataFrame())
{
    //Do something
}
```

But it does nothing, it seems `DataFrame()` is not seen as a default value. And I've tried to overload the function by this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame foo(const DataFrame &data)
{
    //Do something
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame foo()
{
    DataFrame data = DataFrame::create();
    return foo(data);
}
```

But Rcpp tells me there's a conflicting declaration. And I've tried `Nullable`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame foo(Nullable<DataFrame> data_ = R_NilValue)
{
    DataFrame data;
    if (data_.isNotNull())
    {
        data = DataFrame(data_);
    }
    else
    {
        data = DataFrame::create();
    }
    // Do something
}
```

It works well this time, but I wonder:

1. Is this the best (simplest) way to do this?
2. In this case, will `data` passed as copy or reference?

Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If it doesn't work, try something simpler."

A DataFrame is a great type, but it isn't a native SEXP object so that makes creating Rcpp infrastructure hard(er). A DataFrame really is just a list of (equal length) vectors. So on return, I mostly create DataFrame at the very last step, treating the different columns (that constistute it) as the primary object.  And ditto on the way in: get the columns out, work on those vector.

I tried to accumulate a little bit of documentation in the RcppExamples packages, and at the Rcpp Gallery.  But that is it.

(Lastly, "how does it come in ?" that is generally not a worry as Rcpp *always* interfaces R via `.Call()` which takes (zero or more) SEXP and returns a SEXP.  So you are always in the realm of *pointers* and not full outsize objects being copied.

If you have ideas (and better, code) to make things better we are likely going to be all ears.